# How To Make iPhone App Into A Web App

Tags: iphone, mysql, web-applications

If I make a iPhone app, like a grade manager.  What technologies are necessary to make it into a web app.

This includes reading the data from iPhone app in the web app portal (not necessarily editing from web app as of now).

I think I need to transition from using plists to using MYSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would probably be to write a web app that can communicate with the iPhone app, not "converting" the iPhone app to run on the web.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is that, lets say I have a iphone app built.  But I want that data visible on the web, not necessarily editable just readable.

Comment: Yes. So have the iPhone app periodically contact your web app and provide an update via a POST or something.

Comment: Ok, can I still use .plists to write data to from the iphone?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to this:

http://www.phonegap.com/

```
it's an Open Source Mobile Framework That Supports iOS and other platforms.
```

Hope it will give you a guide.